# Basic Auth issue with CKAN

Tags: apache2, ckan

I have CKAN installed on an Ubuntu server. Since we have a requirement to restrict access to anyone, we have configured Basic Auth on the server. We configured apache2 with the auth modules, and using a .htaccess file to manage the credentials. It works as intended to restrict access, but once an end-user enters the username/password, they automatically get logged on to CKAN using those credentials. Unfortunately, it doesn’t allow me to login as myself.

The apache.wsgi file I started with is listed in the docs: http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.0/deployment.html#create-the-wsgi-script-file

Following the guidance described here (https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-discuss/2013-August/002862.html), I added a few new lines to my apache.wsgi file. Unfortunately, it is still not working correctly. e.g. It’s logging into CKAN using the basic auth params.

Below is the current version of my apache.wsgi file.

```
import os
activate_this = os.path.join('/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from paste.deploy import loadapp

config_filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'production.ini')
from paste.script.util.logging_config import fileConfig
fileConfig(config_filepath)
_application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
def application(environ, start_response):
    environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = environ.get('HTTP_X_SCHEME', 'http')
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

Any guidance or recommendations on a way to fix this? Do I need to add additional information to my apache.wsgi file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the line with the pop, not the url_scheme.

i.e. in your apache.wsgi change:

```
application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
```

to:

```
_application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
def application(environ, start_response):
    environ.pop('REMOTE_USER', None)
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```